# How can I undrestand a process will be finished in java programming

Tags: java

I have to run a bat file in a loop in my java code. it means when a process finish for a file another process start after that. I ma using Thread.sleep  in my project after calling process bat file. but the problem is I don't know how a bat file does it take, for some file it takes 1 hour for some of them takes 10 minutes. how can i understand when a process will be finished ?

Comment: How are you running the .bat file?

Comment: I use this command :Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SimsWriter_SpeadWeb.bat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run it by creating a `Process` with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, you can call the `waitFor()` method on the `Process` to wait for it to exit.

Using `Process.exitValue()` you can even read error levels that the .bat files might return.

Comment: It means when I use waitFor() after Runtime.getRuntime().exec() , the program undrestad when a process will be finished? and there is no need i use Thread.sleep()

Comment: Sorry again,but when I put waitfor() the project doesn't wait and run.

Comment: Still I don't know when a process will be finished and I cant estimate a process time .

Comment: Maybe the .bat file uses `start` to run a process? Then it's out of your control. Otherwise, `waitFor()` should wait for the batch file to finish.